# If a 3k+ user edits a post out of the VtC review, does it get out of the review queue?

Tags: discussion

I've heard on the chat, that a post gets out of the review queue if a 3k+ user edits it as part of the review. More details can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/162058/259412). It may be an unintended side-effect, or a non-trivial interpretation of the spirit of the review votes from the software development side of the SE engine.

What happens if a 3k+ user makes this edit out of the review queue? (I.e. right click on the post title, opening it in a new tab and doing the edit in it?) Does this side-effect happen also in this case?

Comment: It's not a rumor, I linked the relevant meta post in [the chat message to you](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/71?m=31822019#31822019).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Ok, I edited the post. I won't link to a chat transcript entry, but I linked Shogs meta SE answer.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Btw, so it is not so bad, because the bump will likely result the restart of the whole voting, this time with +1 close vote.

Comment: It's certainly not an unintended effect - it wouldn't happen if it wasn't explicitly baked in by someone. As to whether it's a "non-trivial" interpretation of the spirit of the review queue, that depends on your trivialometer. SE sees the review queues as instruments for improving questions, and the bump mechanism helps ensure that incomplete edits are unlikely to take the question out of the queue for good, particularly if the question is receiving any attention at all. (And, if it isn't, it's not *that* harmful, either.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a test on [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279038/what-is-the-spatial-extent-of-single-photon), the answer is **no**.

More exactly: after reloading the review entity, it was still an open review.

Comment: I've intentionally selected a question where I wanted to vote with "leave open".